# How knife project a building onto a plane?

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

I want to knife project my building onto a plane so that I can easily make a roof. However when I knife project the result I get the following result:

[image]

The steps I take are:

1. In object mode I select my building and then also select my plane.
2. In edit mode I select both again, set my camera to ortho and set position to <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>.
3. I press <kbd>F3</kbd>, search for knife project and select.

Comment: did you tried up-res the plane ?

Comment: I have tried increasing the resolution as you suggested but it still resulted in the same